# how to backup an img with used data only and NOT backup blank space?

Tags: linux, backup, raspbian

I want to backup my Raspbian systemfiles in case it would be broken and forever gone.But the memory of SD card is 32G,and by using tradditional way dd usually end up creating an img with exact 32G storage.But actually there are only 4G storage used and the other 28G is just blank. And by using win32imager tool ,the result is the same.

My question is: Is it possible to backup an img with only used data so the img could be smaller so I only need smaller space to save the img?

I saw somebody on the net claiming it is possible and here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=raspberrypi.img bs=1MB count=2500
sudo parted raspberrypi.img --script -- mklabel msdos
sudo parted raspberrypi.img --script -- mkpart primary fat32 8192s 122879s
sudo parted raspberrypi.img --script -- mkpart primary ext4 122880s -1

loopdevice=`sudo losetup -f --show raspberrypi.img`
device=`sudo kpartx -va $loopdevice | sed -E 's/.*(loop[0-9])p.*/\1/g' | head -1`
device="/dev/mapper/${device}"
partBoot="${device}p1"
partRoot="${device}p2"
sudo mkfs.vfat $partBoot
sudo mkfs.ext4 $partRoot
sudo mount -t vfat $partBoot /media
sudo cp -rfp /boot/* /media/
sudo umount /media
sudo mount -t ext4 $partRoot /media/
cd /media
sudo dump -0uaf - / | sudo restore -rf -
cd
sudo umount /media
sudo kpartx -d $loopdevice
sudo losetup -d $loopdevice
```

Unfortunately this script does not work for me bacause the img can not be completely created and this script finished with error.

Anybody has any ideas?Thank you very much!

Sincerely,

Helen

Comment: Not an answer, but archiving it into a zip might help to decrease size drastically. I can imagine empty/unallocated space is the same kind of pattern.

Answer (score 1):

After some usage of the system you would need to analyze exactly where those 4 GB are located on your SDcard, so just `dd`ing the beginnig of the device is risky.

I suggest to pipe the image though a compression utility. Even large spaces of no content will take nearly no space in the compressed image:

```
dd if=/dev/sdxxx conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c > sdxxx.image.gz
```

Comment: You are assuming the unused filesystem space are backed with logical blocks that read zero, but that's not necessarily the case...

Comment: In the case of an RZAT (Read Zero After TRIM) SSD, `fstrim` beforehand could help achieve what you thought would work though (if the filesystem wasn't mounted with `discard` option).

Comment: A preformatted NAND medium like an SDcard comes with all blocks set to physical #FFFF, if the card does not contain logic to invert the bits. In either case, this compresses perfectly. I there are `rm`ed files, that you did not `wipe` or overwrite, they still can be restored. So a backup image may well be expected to preserve this behaviour, just like it restores files moved to the trash. If this data is to be excluded from the backup, I suggest to erase it before; an erase is neccessary anyhow to reuse the space. But the question was about "blank space".

Comment: I wouldn't consider data residue (confirmed deletion) as analogous to "Trash" (pending/on-hold deletion), especially in the case of regular backup and when the OP explicitly stated that he wants to only the "used 4G storage" (not *"ever-used"* blocks).

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is acceptable for you to perform the cycle of `shrink filesystem -> backup -> grow filesystem` each time (assuming the filesystem supports both shrinking and growing and is robust enough withstand such repeated cycles without breaking), you should not consider block-level backup (i.e. *partition* image created by dd) but filesystem-level backup (e.g. *filesystem* image created by partclone or so which will skip unused blocks in a *filesystem-aware manner*) or file-based backup (e.g. tar, rsync...).

Comment: If you do this, remember to also backup partition table and boot sector or you won't be able to restore your system!

Answer (score 0):

Use a system imaging tool like Ghost (pay-for) or clonezilla (free and Free).

To clone a Pi image, you'll need to put the SD card in a computer, boot clonezilla, and dump an image of the entire SD card to a file on a hard drive somewhere.  Restoring is the opposite process.

Answer (score -1):

#### The answer is yes.

You must have a knowledge of exact data that you would like to backup.  Let say you have 4G of data in a 32G Storage disk.

Use: `seek and count` with dd.

To copy 4G from a drive

```
dd=if/dev/sdb1 of=mybackup.iso bs=1M count=4096 conv=noerror,sync
```

The above will copy 4G from partition /dev/sdb1.  However you can decide to copy data from xMB to xGB

```
dd=if/dev/sdb1 of=mybackup.iso bs=1M seek=xMB count=x noerror,sync
```

we used seek to move forward, so seek=2G will start to copy from 2G not from the beginning, count=x, is amount of data that need to be copied, so count=4096 will copy 4096 x 1MB = 4G

Don't forget to use `lsblk` to show your block

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  37.3G  0 disk
|-sda1   8:1    0  19.5G  0 part /
|-sda2   8:2    0  17.2G  0 part /home
`-sda3   8:3    0   511M  0 part [SWAP]

fdisk /dev/sdb
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        4096    40962047    20478976   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        40962048    77111295    18074624   83  Linux
/dev/sda3        77111296    78157823      523264   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question: by using "fdisk /dev/sdb" ,the result shows the value of "Start" and "End" of corresponding partition,does thses two value corresponds to the value "Seek" and "Seek+Count" that you mentioned?@LasVegasCoder

Comment: @HelenCui The Start and End displayed by fdisk command does refers to Start and End of Sector or Block of you disk or partition.  I included that to show your disk partitions in case `lsblk` is not installed on your system

Comment: You are assuming the filesystem will only use a single range of contiguous logical blocks from the beginning of the partition...

Comment: This is only reliable if you have shrunk the filesystem to use only the first `count=` blocks of the partition.

Comment: `seek=` in this case makes no sense at all.